# MySQL Text datatype acting like Int datatype

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I have an interesting problem. I created a table whose column is clearly defined as a text datatype (The name column). When I insert a string into it, it returns a 0. When I simply input an integer, it will store that integer. So long story short it is treating that column as an integer instead of a text field. This is the create statement (I am using php and inserting into a wordpress database).

```
global $wpdb;
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
    oid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    total FLOAT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    phone TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (oid)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    dbDelta( $sql );
```

and this is the insert statement

```
global $wpdb;
$data = array('user_id' => $_POST['uid'], 'name' => 965, 'date' => $_POST['CurrentDay'], 'total' => $_POST['Total'], 'email' => $_POST['Email'], 'phone' => $_POST['Phone']);
    $format = array('%s','%d');
    $wpdb->insert($table, $data, $format);
    $my_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

You can ignore the 965 for the 'name' column (which returns 965 for that column and row)... I tried it as a string... 'name' => 'Shane',... Every time I put a string, it returns a 0 in that column.

Comment: *I tried it as a string... `'name' => "Shane"`* 1) MySQL uses single quotes for string literals. 2) MySQL have no strict datatypes, the data is converted to the needed datatype implicitly, or it truncates the value when convertion is not possible generating warning or error (depends on a problem type and SQL mode).

Comment: My bad. I am fairly certain that I used 'Shane' and not "Shane" when I was testing. It was probably in formatting for the post. Yet that still doesn't explain why the other fields (email and phone) are handled correctly, while the 'name' field isn't. - Just tested the 'Shane' and it still returned 0 for that column and row. @Akina

Comment: Do you use `mysqli`? if so where do you find `->insert` method? I don't see it in [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli.php)... or you use some custom lib? specify it...

Comment: Okay. Sorry, left out a detail. Its a word press database, so there is some built in functions... @Akina I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: Please explain why data array contains 6 values whereas format array contains only 2 values... and you have specified `'%d'` datatype for 2nd parameter (`'name'`) which means `integer` - so why you're surprised that string value is truncated to zero?

Comment: That did it. Sorry, first time to actually do this. I missed the formatting variable when I copied and pasted the snippet... I altered the code and it works. If you would like to submit a formal answer, that'd be cool. Thank you very much. I just needed the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wpdb->insert](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/) method accepts 3 parameters. 2nd parameter specifies the values with must be inserted, 3rd parameter positionally specified the formats of the values to be inserted.

In your code the format parameter contains 2 values - i.e. it specifies the format for first 2 parameters. All another parameters are treated as "the type is not specified", so they are transferred as string type ones (the most common type which may transfer all another types) unless otherwise specified in `wpdb->$field_types`.

1st parameter is `'user_id' => $_POST['uid']`, and the format specification for it is `'%s'` which means "string".

2nd parameter is `'name' => 965`, and the format specification for it is `'%d'` which means "integer". So inserting a string type value into this parameter causes the convertion to the integer data type, and the result is zero.

In your case I do not see the necessity to specify the data types at all. Simply skip 3rd (optional) parameter.

Comment: Thank you once again. I can't believe I overlooked something so simple.